# Showing that the borel-$\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb R^d$ is generated by open subsets of $\mathbb R^d$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

I would like to show that the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B_\mathbb R$over $\mathbb R^d$  is generated by the set $\mathcal O_\mathbb R$, which denotes the set of all open subsets in $\mathbb R^d$. I already showed this proposition for $d=1$, but how do I generalise it for any $d \in \mathbb N$? I do not quite know how to start, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Isn't this the definition? What definition are you using?

Comment: @Thompson My definition of a Borel sigma algebra is, that it is the sigma algebra generated by the set of half open intervals in $\mathbb R$

Comment: So what's your definition of the Borel sigma algebra *on $\mathbb{R}^n$*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$ is defined to be generated by half open intervals $[a,b)$ for $a < b$, then I suppose that you define the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R^d$ as the product $\sigma$-algebra with the identification $\mathbb R^d \simeq \mathbb R\times \cdots \times \mathbb R$; that is, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R^d$ is generated by sets $\prod^d_{i=1} [a_i, b_i)$. Is this correct? If so, you will show this the same way for $d=1$ as for $d \ge 2$.

Let $\Sigma$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets. Since any set of the form $\prod^d_{i=1} [a_i, b_i)$ can be written as a countable intersection of the sets $\big\{ \prod^d_{i=1} (a_i-1/n, b_i)\big\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ which are open, we see that each of these sets is in $\Sigma$. But the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing these sets is $\mathcal B_{\mathbb R}$ so this shows that $\mathcal B_{\mathbb R} \subseteq \Sigma$.

Likewise since the sets $\prod^d_{i=1} (a_i, b_i)$ generate the topology on $\mathbb R^d$ (and since the topology is second countable), any open set in $\mathbb R^d$ can be written as a countable union of sets of the form $\prod^d_{i=1} (a_i, b_i)$. However, notice that $\prod^d_{i=1} (a_i, b_i)$ can be written as the countable union of the sets $\big\{ \prod^d_{i=1} [a_i+1/n, b_i) \big\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$. This shows that each of  $\prod^d_{i=1} (a_i, b_i)$ is in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and thus every open set is in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. But $\Sigma$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all the open sets so $\Sigma \subseteq \mathcal B_\mathbb R$.